# Is it possible to change the asset issuer?

Tags: stellar-core, assets, trustline

After issuing the asset I need to change the asset issuer, all trustors will remain trusting the same asset but the issuer is diffrent.

scenario-

issuer 1 - issued asset `Dummyasset` now need to transfer all the rights of issuer to the other address, or make it a new owner of asset.

Answer (score 2):

Since the asset issuing account is determined by the ID of the account that physically created the asset, there wouldn't be any way to "change" who issued an asset.

The only solution I see is to issue a new asset with the other address, and have previous trusting addresses open a trustline with the new asset.

Answer (score 2):

A Stellar Asset is differentiated primarily based on the Issuer. Hence changing Issuer is like creating a new asset on its own. So it is not NOT possible to change the Issuer.

But, you can create a new Asset with the same name and launch an application that can facilitate 1:1 swap with old asset to new asset, easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can not, but you could just set a new signer and disable the issuer accounts original key by setting master_weight to zero.